# match any a-z/A-Z and - character after certain regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

i need a certain string to be in this format:
[0000] anyword

so between the [] brackets i need 4 numbers, followed by a whitespace. after that only characters ranging from a to z and - characters are allowed.

so this should be allowed:

[0000] foo-bar

[0000] foo

[0000] foo-bar-foo

etc..

so far i have this:

```
\[[0-9]{4}\]\s
```

this matches the [0000] , so it maches the brackets with 4 numbers in it and the whitespace. 
i can't seem to find something that allows charachters after that. i've tried putting a single "." at the end of the expression as this should match any character but this doesnt seem to be working.

```
\[[0-9]{4}\]\s^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*$
```

the above isn't working either..

i need this expression as a Validationexpression for an asp.net custom validator.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm uncertain of .NET's flavour but this works for your input: http://regexr.com?30sb7. Note that `^` is typically start-of-line, and `-` has to be first in `[]` to indicate literal rather than a range.

Comment: thanks, this is working. if you submit it as an answer i can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your input: http://regexr.com/?30sb7. Unlike Cornstalk's answer it does not capture anything, and `-` can indeed be placed later in a range if it's escaped.

Answer (score 2):

`(\[[0-9]{4}\])\s+([A-z\-]+)` should hopefully work. It'll capture the numbers and letters into two capture groups as well.

Comment: I would replace the first group with `\[([0-9]{4})\]` because saving the `[` and `]` isn't really necessary ...

Comment: That depends on his needs... But yes, that is something worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
@"\[[0-9]{4}\] [a-zA-Z]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)*"
```

Comment: this regex only allows one optional `-` and fails to match the example `[0000] foo-bar-foo`